# For gtest, how to mock methods which have the same name, but different types

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

I use Gtest to verify my C++ code, and now I face a mocking problem.
For several reasons, I have some methods, which have the same name, but different type arguments and implementation, like

```
void foo(int& i);
void foo(double& d);
void foo(float& f);
```

For them, I make mock methods, like

```
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(int&));
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(double&));
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(float&));
```

However, I could not use EXPECT_CALL for them. In a test code, I set action for foo(int), like

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_object, foo(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(10),Return()));
```

but, compiler failed because target is ambiguous among int, double and float.

Is there any way to use EXPECT_CALL for specific type mock method?

I failed to use testing::MatcherCast and testing::SafeMatcherCast, because they only accept const type. However, I need to update the argument, so I could not use const.

Comment: Did you try something like, `EXPECT_CALL(mock_object, foo(AnyOf(Eq(0),Ne(0))));`? Otherwise, I think you need to implement you own matcher...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use typed wildcard ([documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.10.0/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#wildcard)):

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_object, foo(An<int&>())).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<0>(10));
EXPECT_CALL(mock_object, foo(A<double&>())).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<0>(10.));
```

`A<>` and `An<>` mean exactly the same, they have two names just for nicer reading.
See it online on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/89ac7fsdq)

---

Side note: You don't have to `Return()` from `void` method.

Comment: Thank you, Yksisarvinen. It works for me without linking errors.